# WordPress Sort Custom Post Type by Taxonomy Name in Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type of **Home Plan** and a custom taxonomy of **Community**.

I'd like to be able to sort alphabetically by the **Community** column in the admin area. In this case, **Home Plans** will only ever be assigned to one **Community**. Is this possible?

I've been researching for a while, but most of my results all deal with custom meta columns.

[image: WordPress admin Custom Post Type Interface]

Comment: Its not possible, you would need a custom query that pulls posts including term name assigned into it, then sort it using term name value

Comment: So it is possible, but I'd have to manually add a new custom column, as opposed to using the default taxonomy column?

Comment: you would need to create your own admin page that pulls custom post type based on your own query, wordpress editor uses query var which is not possible to accomplish what you need.

Comment: There are many tutorials online about sorting admin columns in wordpress. For instance: [clicky](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-make-your-custom-column-sortable--wp-25095) and [clicky](http://wpdreamer.com/2014/04/how-to-make-your-wordpress-admin-columns-sortable/). Be sure to use your cpt in the hooks: `manage_edit-{post_type}_sortable_columns`.